# What does blogging services like: blogger.com, tumblr.com. use to make dynamic subdomains

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I'm trying to make a website that can host subdomains dynamically like the blogging services, Is there any solution to overcome this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be using wildcard DNS. Please read it here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wildcard_DNS_record
This could also help https://codex.wordpress.org/Configuring_Wildcard_Subdomains

Comment: In which file I should place the DNS record? I'm using windows 8 or Can I make wildcard domain in windows hosts file?

Comment: Im not sure how it is done in windows. Usually if u have cpanel u just need to add an A record with * as name and ur ip as Address (as far as I know)